# ANTLR4 - Lexer can't match a token made of fragments

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4, mismatch

I'm having trouble with this grammar

```
prog : start line* end ;
start : SIMBOL START NUM NL ;

SIMBOL : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUM : [0-9]+ ;
START : S T A R T ;
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
NL  :   '\r'? '\n' ;

fragment A : [aA] ;
fragment B : [bB] ;
fragment C : [cC] ;
fragment D : [dD] ;
fragment E : [eE] ;
fragment F : [fF] ;
fragment G : [gG] ;
fragment H : [hH] ;
fragment I : [iI] ;
fragment J : [jJ] ;
fragment K : [kK] ;
fragment L : [lL] ;
fragment M : [mM] ;
fragment N : [nN] ;
fragment O : [oO] ;
fragment P : [pP] ;
fragment Q : [qQ] ;
fragment R : [rR] ;
fragment S : [sS] ;
fragment T : [tT] ;
fragment U : [uU] ;
fragment V : [vV] ;
fragment W : [wW] ;
fragment X : [xX] ;
fragment Y : [yY] ;
fragment Z : [zZ] ;
```

And the string I'm testing is the following

```
test    start   1010
        add     30
        end     simbol
```

The 'test' word is matched by the SIMBOL rule, which is correct. Problem is that 'start' is not matched.

By using a ErrorListener i get the following message in the syntaxError method

```
mismatched input 'start' expecting START
```

At position 1:8 which is the beginning of the 'start' word.

I'm new to ANTLR and i can't figure out where i am wrong.

BTW, I'm using ANTLR 4.7.1 with it's proper runtime in python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally forgot that the lexer rules order matters. I had the SIMBOL rule above the START rule so the 'start' word was being mismatched as a SIMBOL token and not a START token.

I fixed the problem by moving the SIMBOL rule to the end of the grammar.